# Custom subviews in iOS Keyboard

Tags: ios

How can a custom subview be added to the iOS keyboard for an app, not global using the custom keyboard?

I would like to add functionality to the keyboard in an app, such as stickers and an additional subview in between the text input area and the top of the key subview.

Should a new keyboard be created from scratch? Or can the keyboard be extended?

How are the custom subviews hooked up to a controller for handling? E.g. facebook or viber have stickers that can be selected, how are these subviews managed and connected to the VC?

Comment: I think Apple won't like it this way... you might want to create keyboard extension instead, that is exactly for that. If you really want, you can iterate over root windows subviews recursively, learn the keyboard objects layout and then add subviews...

Comment: hmm, thats too risky. The extension is a keyboard that needs to be added via the settings app. How do apps have custom keyboards inside their app only? E.g. Facebook or Viber?

Comment: From iOS 8.x you can include extensions inside your app :)